# CMake won't link when moved to 64-bit system

Tags: cmake

I had been using CMake without problems when I discovered my Ubuntu was installed as 32-bit even though my processor is actually 64-bit. Whoops.

I reinstalled Ubuntu and the various dev packages I was using. Now when I run make I get errors like this:

```
[  1%] make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so', needed by `/home...
```

/usr/lib/**i386-linux-gnu**/libQtGui.so` doesn't exist but /usr/lib/**x86_64-linux-gnu**/libQtGui.so does.

I have run `ccmake` to reconfigure and regenerate the makefile and run `make clean` but it's still looking for 64-bit libraries. If I expand the ccmake options I can see the 32-bit library path in various variables.

I have created a new build directory and run ccmake from scratch and this works but now I have to remember all the nondefault settings I put in and reproduce them in the new build environment.

I'd rather just "upgrade" the CMake setup to 64-bit, preserving my own flags. Is this possible?

Comment: Sometimes that CMakeCache.txt file just needs to be deleted. I don't think that happens on `clean` for whatever reason.

Comment: Deleting CMakeCache.txt fixes the libraries but it also deletes my flags and other settings changes.

Comment: How about [cmake -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables) ?

Comment: Extract your custom settings from your CMakeCache.txt (it's just text) and start over.  If it's your source, put all that stuff in CMakeLists.txt instead of manually adjusting the cachefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like removing your Cmake cache, you can edit it and search-and-replace to modify the paths of libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a new CMake cache:

```
rm CMakeCache.txt
```

Comment: That destroys my other settings

Comment: Indeed, but you don't have the choice, when you change the architecture.